# Is there a way to Tailwind styles from spilling over into other applications? (Isolating tailwind styles to component library)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a React library using Tailwind for styling for the library, one of the issues I'm coming across is that the tailwind styles "spill over" into the applications that implement the library? Struggling to find clear solutions on how to go about preventing this, anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will simply need to change the folders that Tailwind is looking for files to parse when building.

tailwind.config.js

```
export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './public/js/preline/dist/*.js',
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
    ],
]
```

Just simply change the line that says `'./resources/views/**/*.blade.php',` to whichever folder you would like it to be looking in.

This will force Tailwind to only build the CSS based on the styles included in the tags in the files of that particular folder. Also, as stated above, adding a prefix to Tailwind will also further stop it. I am currently using Bootstrap 5 and Tailwind, and there are a number of conflicts, which is common amongst a few libraries.

```
export default {
    content: [...],
    prefix: 'tw-',
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add [prefixes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) to your classes via the configuration for Tailwind.

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  // other configuration options
  prefix: 'comp-',
}
```

This would add the *'comp'* prefix to all classes generated from that configuration. In the case of this question, it would prepend the *'comp'* prefix to all classes used within the component library.